# What's the difference between System level Project Roles and Project level Project Roles in Jira?

Tags: jira

We host our own instance of Jira.

While logged into Jira as an Admin, I can get to System > Roles and add groups of users to a Role, in this case Users.

Now if I go to a pre-existing project (Projects > [project name] > Roles), the group I added to the Users Role is not shown. I have to add it again to this Role.

My problem is that we originally were just going to use it in the Dev group, but decided to roll it out to the rest of the company. So I already have 12 pre-existing projects, and about 10 groups I need to add to the Users Role so they can attach files and manage watchers and all that.

Is it possible to add each group just once to the Users Role in System > Roles and have it cascade out to the rest of the existing projects? Or am I stuck adding each group to each project individually?

Answer (score 0):

`Users/Groups` added under `System > Roles` are the default users used when creating a new Project and don't get applied out once a project is already created.

So when a project gets created these values copy into the project where it lives it life of having its own unique users and groups.

Your best bet is using groups of users and adding that group to the role, this way you can add users to the group as required and it be applied across all projects.